# Does an APP_START action contradict Redux architecture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am build a React/Redux application. The application requires a connection to an MQTT message broker (via WebSocket). When reloading the page (or navigating in for the first time), the user *must* connect to the broker to do anything in the app.

My initial thought is to dispatch an `APP_START` event and use Redux-thunk to wire up external state. Obviously, [reacting to @@redux/init is not OK](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/186) and part of me feels that I might be me trying to shoehorn event-based OO into Redux.

Is it an anti-pattern to have actions like `APP_START` in a Redux app? If so, what patterns are more suitable alternatives?

Comment: It's not an anti-pattern. Application initialisation is also an event as a mouse click.

Comment: I've been using this strategy myself for quite a while now, honestly believe its quite explicit and useful.

Comment: It is fine, it could be compared to the `load` event. By the way, consider if `APP_LOAD` or `CONNECT_TO_BROKER` would be a better fit than `APP_START` for your case.